# Pseudo-parallel depth-first search

Tags: java, performance, graph, concurrency, depth-first-search

I'm writing a small program that generates a file containing an adjancency matrix, it then reads from that file, constructs a graph and does something like a parallel depth-first search (dfs) on it.

How can I make the dfs part faster, because now it seems to be doing a lot of nothing (each thread just sets the nodes parent and marks it as visited)?

Is this implementation even ok?

I'm open to any implementation changes and ideas.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;


public class Graph {

/**
 * A map containing the node number and a boolean to decide if it is visited.
 */
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, AtomicBoolean> visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

/**
 * A map containing a list of neighbors for each node. 
 */
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> adjacencyList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
/**
 * A map containing a node number and a node object.
 */
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Node> treeNodes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Options options = new Options();

    setOptions(options);        
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = null;
    try {
        cmd = parser.parse( options, args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    determinePrintLocation(cmd);

    PrintStream originalStream = System.out;

    Graph graph = new Graph();

    determineGraphCreation(cmd, graph);
    doExecution(cmd, graph);
    shouldWriteTreeToFile(cmd, graph);

}

/**
 * Determines if the tree information from the program execution should be written to a file.
 * @param cmd
 * @param graph
 */
protected static void shouldWriteTreeToFile(CommandLine cmd, Graph graph) {
    if(cmd.hasOption("gf")) {
        String outputFileName = cmd.getOptionValue("gf");
        graph.writeToFile(outputFileName);
    }
}

/**
 * Determines with how many threads should the algorithm be executed.
 * @param cmd
 * @param graph
 */
protected static void doExecution(CommandLine cmd, Graph graph) {
    if(cmd.hasOption("t")) {
        String threadCountString = cmd.getOptionValue("t");
        Integer threadCount = Integer.valueOf(threadCountString);
        graph.execute(threadCount);
    } else {
        graph.execute(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Determines if the graph should be created from a file or on the go.
 * @param cmd
 * @param graph
 */
protected static void determineGraphCreation(CommandLine cmd, Graph graph) {
    if(cmd.hasOption("n")) {
        String nodeCountString = cmd.getOptionValue("n", "1");
        Integer nodeCount = Integer.valueOf(nodeCountString);
        graph.generateGraph(nodeCount);
    } else if (cmd.hasOption("i")) {
        String fileName = cmd.getOptionValue("i");
        graph.constructGraphFromFile(fileName);
    }
}

/**
 * Determines the location of the print file in which the 
 * thread execution time and data should be written.
 * @param cmd
 */
protected static void determinePrintLocation(CommandLine cmd) {
    if(cmd.hasOption("q")) {
        System.setOut(new NullPrintStream());
    } else if(cmd.hasOption("o")) {
        String fileName = cmd.getOptionValue("o", "output_file.txt");
            try {
                System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)), true));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create output stream.", e);
            }

    }
}

/**
 * Sets the command line options.
 * @param options
 */
protected static void setOptions(Options options) {
    options.addOption("n", true, "The number of nodes of the graph.");
    options.addOption("i", true, "The input file for the graph.");
    options.addOption("o", true, "The output file for the application");
    options.addOption("t", true, "The amount of threads to be used");
    options.addOption("q", false, "Determine if there should be output");
    options.addOption("gf",true, "File to which to write the graph information");
}


/**
 * Executes the parallel DFS.
 */
private void execute(int threadCount) {        

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(threadCount);
    // check each node, because the graph may not be connected
    System.out.println("Algorithm execution started with " + threadCount + " threads");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(Integer node : visited.keySet()) {
        if(visited.get(node).get()) {
            continue;
        }
        DFS dfs = new DFS(node);
        pool.invoke(dfs);
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Algorithm execution took " + elapsedTime + " nanoseconds");

}

/**
 * Writes the graph data to a file.
 * @param fileName
 */
public void writeToFile(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try(BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {

        for(Node node : treeNodes.values()) {
            bwr.write("Node number: " + node.getNode());
            bwr.newLine();

            if(node.getParent() != null){
                bwr.write("Node parent: " + node.getParent().getNode());
                bwr.newLine();
            }           
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create output stream for the graph data.", ex);
    }

}

/**
 * Generates a graph in memory.
 * @param nodeCount
 */
private void generateGraph(int nodeCount) {

    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(nodeCount);

    System.out.println("Started graph creation.");

    for(int i=0 ; i < nodeCount ; i++) {

        List<Integer> neighbours = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int j=0; j < nodeCount ; j++) {
            int choice = random.nextInt(2);
            if(choice == 1) {
                neighbours.add(j);
            }               
        }

        adjacencyList.put(i, neighbours);
        visited.put(i, new AtomicBoolean(false));
        treeNodes.put(i, new Node(i));
    }

    System.out.println("Graph created.");
}

/**
 * Construct a graph from an adjacency matrix in a file.
 * @param fileName
 */
public void constructGraphFromFile(String fileName) {

    System.out.println("Construction of graph from file started");

    File file = new File(fileName);

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        String numberLine = br.readLine();
        int nodeCount = Integer.valueOf(numberLine);

        visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(nodeCount);
        int count = 0;
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            String[] data = line.split("\\s+");

            List<Integer> neighbours = new LinkedList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                if(data[i].equals("1")) {
                    neighbours.add(i);
                }
            }

            adjacencyList.put(count, neighbours);

            treeNodes.put(count, new Node(count));
            visited.put(count, new AtomicBoolean(false));

            count++;

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to construct graph from file.", ex);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Construction of graph from file finished");
}

private void constructGraphFile(String fileName, int size) {
    System.out.println("Construction of graph file started.");
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create file with name: " + fileName, ex);
    }
    try(BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))){
        bwr.write(String.valueOf(size));
        bwr.newLine();

        ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j=0; j < size; j++) {
                builder.append(random.nextInt(2));
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            String trimed = builder.toString().trim();
            bwr.write(trimed);
            bwr.newLine();                
        }            

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Graph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to construct adjecancy matrix file.", ex);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Construction of graph file finished.");

}

/**
 * Class implementing {@link RecursiveAction} which does the actual computation.
 * @author aleksandar
 *
 */
private class DFS extends RecursiveAction{

    int node;

    public DFS(int node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();           

        AtomicBoolean isVisited = visited.get(node);            
        if(isVisited.getAndSet(true)) {
            return;
        }

        //System.out.println("Executing thread " + threadName + ". For node " + node);
        List<Integer> adjList = adjacencyList.get(node);
        Node parent = treeNodes.get(node);

        for(Integer neighbour : adjList) {

            Node child = treeNodes.get(neighbour);

            Integer childNode = child.getNode();
            if(visited.get(childNode).get()) {
                continue;
            }

            child.setParent(parent);

            DFS dfs = new DFS(neighbour);
            dfs.fork();
        }

       // System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + ". Finished work on node " + node + " and returned to thread pool");            
    }

}

/**
 * Class representing a node in the graph.
 * @author aleksandar
 *
 */
private class Node {
    private Integer node;
    private Node parent;

    public Node(int node) {
        this.node = node;
    } 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.node);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.node, other.node)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   

    public Integer getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}

}
```

**PS:** Updated with the latest version. It works with command line arguments, but for testing can use the methods directly. The `compute` method and whole synchonisation idea, I think can be improved.

The helper class if needed.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * Class for redirecting a stream to nowhere.<br>
 * (Something like dev\null on UNIX)
 */
public class NullPrintStream extends PrintStream {

public NullPrintStream() {
  super(new NullByteArrayOutputStream());
}

private static class NullByteArrayOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {

@Override
public void write(int b) {
  // do nothing
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
  // do nothing
}

@Override
public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
  // do nothing
}

}

}
```

Comment: `Is this realisation even ok ?` Does it work as intended? If it doesn't, you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Mast Yes it works right. When printing the node and it's parent everything is ok. I even tested it with some visualisation. The realisation part was more of in the lines of "Is the idea of doing it like this, stupid or not ?" :D